# SoundPool stops playing

Tags: android, soundpool

I have a button that when pressed sounds a short sound effect with SoundPool. the file is a 16k mp3.

 **The sound effect works for hundreds of button clicks, but at some point i get this error (and the sound isn't playing for clicks anymore):**

```
E/AudioFlinger(   34): no more track names available
E/AudioTrack(  904): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
E/SoundPool(  904): Error creating AudioTrack
W/AudioFlinger(   34): write blocked for 81 msecs, 4573 delayed writes, thread
xb3f0
```

onCreate:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
soundpool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
soundpool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        loaded = true;
    }
});

//save the effect somewhere:
MyUtil.regularSound = soundpool.load(this, R.raw.regular_click,1);
```

onClick:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
float actualVol = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float maxVol = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float vol = actualVol/maxVol;
if (loaded) {
    soundpool.play(MyUtil.regularSound,vol,vol,1,0,1f);
}
```

before starting another intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(con, EndScreen.class);
if (soundpool != null) {
    soundpool.release();
    soundpool = null;
}
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: My 2 cent worth: Could be that the soundpool release has not been handled (GC) and that the slot is still active as far as soundpool goes. you have set maxstreams to 10. Just a thought.

Answer (score 4):

I just spent hours with the same problem.

The -12 error means that sound allocated to the app is out of memory. using `.finish()` doesn't release the memory of SoundPool. You have to use `.release()`.

In my app I have a soundPool.release() on the onclick method that starts the next activity,

Changing the sound formats didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Im getting the same error. The thing I did was to try to resample the track, convert it to OGG format and change the quality to 0. I did all this with [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/)

Comment: What's in OGG that make the problem disappear ?

Answer (score 0):

You try code it: here

```
    /*
    private SoundPool mSoundPool;
    private SparseArray<Integer> mSoundPoolMap;
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    */
    public static void clear() {
        if (mSoundManager != null) {
            mSoundManager.mSoundPool = null;
            mSoundManager.mAudioManager = null;
            mSoundManager.mSoundPoolMap = null;
        }
        mSoundManager = null;
    }
```